# Storing more than a million .txt files into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a set of more than million records all of them in the `.txt` format. Each `file.txt` has just one line:

> 'user_name', 'user_nickname', 24, 45

I need to run a distribution check on the aggregated list of numeric features from the million files. Hence, I needed to aggregate these files into large data frame. The approach I have been following is as follows:

```py
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

import sqlite3

connex = sqlite3.connect("data/processed/aggregated-records.db")

files_lst = glob.glob("data/raw/*.txt")

files_read_count = 1

for file_name in files_lst:
    data_df = pd.read_csv(file_name, 
                          header=None, 
                          names=['user_name', 'user_nickname',  
                                 'numeric_1', 'numeric_2'])

    data_df['date_time'] = os.path.basename(file_name).strip(".txt")

    data_df.to_sql(name=file_name, con=connex, if_exists="append", index=False)

    files_read_count += 1

    if (files_read_count % 10000) == 0:
        print(files_read_count, " files read")
```

The issue I have is that with this approach, I am able to write to the database at a very slow pace (about 10,000 files in an hour). Is there any way to run this faster?

Comment: `pd.read_csv` is a _very slow_ function, and your data is trivial. Use the `csv` module, avoid pandas altogether. Prepare a complete dataset and only _then_ write it to the database.

Comment: @DYZ Awesome... let me try this out and get back

Comment: OMG... the difference upon shifting to `csv` is phenomenal...  I will submit my answer below... Thank you @DYZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code cuts the processing time to 10,000 files a minute. This is an implementation of the suggestion from @DYZ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058953/storing-more-than-a-million-txt-files-into-a-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment94951786_54058953).

```
import csv, glob

with open('data/processed/aggregated-data.csv', 'w') as aggregated_csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(aggregated_csv_file, delimiter=',')

    files_lst = glob.glob("data/raw/*.txt")

    files_merged_count = 1

    for file in files_lst:

        with open(file) as input_file:

            csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',')

            for row in csv_reader:
                writer.writerow(row)

        if (files_merged_count % 10000) == 0:
            print(files_merged_count, "files merged")

        files_merged_count += 1
```

Comment: You might have referenced the comment that inspired your answer.

Comment: @DYZ, I should have indeed (edited the post now). Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Unix you could try concatenating the files using a shell script first and then reading that final resultant file.

For e.g. `find -name '*.txt' -type f -exec cat {} \; > combinedfile.txt`

Now you can use pandas or anything else to move it to the database.

Comment: I do have access to a Unix shell. Let me try this out and get back.